# UIImageView rejects `image` after user chooses it from their library - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I've got some basic code to let the user pick an image and set it to an already created `UIImageView`:

```
- (void)addAvatarImageView {
    self.avatarImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 83, 83)];
    self.avatarImageView.imageURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:self.user[@"avatar"]];
    [self.avatarView addSubview:self.avatarImageView];
}
```

and the picker creation:

```
- (void)showAvatarPicker {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePickController.delegate = self;
    imagePickController.allowsEditing = YES;
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:imagePickController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

and the picker delegate:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    [self.avatarImageView setImage:image];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I can breakpoint inside the delegate method and it goes in there fine, but the `UIImageView` does not show the new image at all. I can't even remove the image that is present either. Any ideas?

Comment: i think UIImageView does not have property called imageURl so problem might be there

Comment: @xphobia https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem? If you did, please share.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go on a limb here and say that the error is in the portion of the code that you are not showing: where you instantiate your picker. More presicely, you may not have set `allowsEditing` to yes. So take a look below

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

---

Alternatively you can just read the original image using `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` instead of your current `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage`.

Comment: oh man I so wish that would have been the answer, but if you see my edit, I already have that in there

Answer (score 0):

change UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]; to UIImage *image = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];